# Complicated relationship Q

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, query, complexity

I'm trying to do a query to find products that *aren't* on the customer's authorized products list, and it's breaking my brain.

Each customer has an authorized product group list, and within a product group each entry might consist of a Product ID, a Product Category ID, Vendor Number, Price Schedule ID, or Brand ID (all different columns on the Product record).

Many authorized product group lists have a mix of 2 or more kinds of entries, and often there's some overlap between the different columns used as selection criteria. Of course, there's a code on the product group list item that indicates which column the entry is based on, so it's easy enough to parse.

On the Product side, I'd be looking for products without an "Inactive" flag that aren't on the authorized list for each customer.

The tables look roughly like this:

**Customer**

| CustomerID | AuthorizedListID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 345 |
| 2 | 345 |
| 3 | 117 |

**Authorized List**

| ListID | ListName |
| --- | --- |
| 117 | Frozen goods |
| 345 | Pizza |

**Authorized List Items**

| ListKey | ItemRefNo | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 117 | 68 | BRND |
| 117 | 202 | ITEM |
| 117 | 1415 | ITEM |
| 117 | 3012 | ITEM |
| 117 | 61152 | CATG |
| 117 | 31667 | PRIC |
| 345 | 9615 | ITEM |
| 345 | 2100 | ITEM |
| 345 | 13229 | VNDR |
| 345 | 87211 | CATG |

**Products**

| ProductID | CategoryKey | PriceKey | VendorKey | BrandKey | Inactive |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 202 | 61152 | 113 | 45529 | 16 | 0 |
| 1415 | 4990 | 5601 | 882 | 41009 | 0 |
| 2100 | 61152 | 37772 | 9101 | 20900 | 0 |
| 3557 | 87211 | 4101 | 17743 | 23777 | 0 |
| 4027 | 5193 | 644 | 882 | 68 | 0 |
| 4028 | 5193 | 580 | 882 | 68 | 0 |
| 9615 | 87211 | 1512 | 17743 | 8738 | 0 |
| 13017 | 87211 | 4040 | 13229 | 23795 | 0 |
| 42500 | 87211 | 20155 | 17743 | 4355 | 0 |
| 53529 | 1011 | 31667 | 13229 | 602 | 1 |

While I have a fair bit of SQL experience, this has a level of complexity that's beyond me at this point...so part of what's messing me up is that I don't even know how to succinctly and accurately describe what I'm trying to do so I can do a search for it. I don't even know the appropriate tags for this question. Also, I forgot to mention earlier: T-SQL for SQL Server 2016R2.

Expected results would be a set of records with CustomerID and ProductID columns where the product wasn't in the authorized list for the customer and Inactive = 0. Ideally, this would be a view.

I've gotten as far as this query:

```
SELECT C.*, 
A.ItemRefNo,
A.Type,
CASE 
    WHEN CA.ProductId IS NOT NULL THEN CA.ProductId 
    WHEN B.ProductId IS NOT NULL THEN B.ProductId
    WHEN V.ProductId IS NOT NULL THEN V.ProductId 
    WHEN P.ProductId IS NOT NULL THEN P.ProductId 
    WHEN A.Type = 'ITEM' THEN A.ItemRefNo 
    ELSE NULL 
    END
AS ProductId
FROM Customer C
INNER JOIN authorizedListItems A
ON C.AuthorizedListId = A.ListKey 
LEFT JOIN products CA
    ON A.ItemRefNo = CA.CategoryKey 
    AND A.Type = 'CATG'
LEFT JOIN products B
    ON A.ItemRefNo = B.BrandKey 
    AND A.Type = 'BRND' 
LEFT JOIN products V
    ON A.ItemRefNo = V.VendorKey 
    AND A.Type = 'VNDR' 
LEFT JOIN products P
    ON A.ItemRefNo = P.PriceKey 
    AND A.Type = 'PRIC'
```

Query results:

| CustomerId | AuthorizedListId | ItemRefNo | Type | ProductId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 117 | 68 | BRND | 4027 |
| 3 | 117 | 68 | BRND | 4028 |
| 3 | 117 | 202 | ITEM | 202 |
| 3 | 117 | 1415 | ITEM | 1415 |
| 3 | 117 | 3012 | ITEM | 3012 |
| 3 | 117 | 61152 | CATG | 202 |
| 3 | 117 | 61152 | CATG | 2100 |
| 1 | 345 | 9615 | ITEM | 9615 |
| 2 | 345 | 9615 | ITEM | 9615 |
| 1 | 345 | 2100 | ITEM | 2100 |
| 2 | 345 | 2100 | ITEM | 2100 |
| 1 | 345 | 13229 | VNDR | 13017 |
| 1 | 345 | 13229 | VNDR | 53529 |

The result I'd like to see is:

| CustomerId | ProductId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 202 |
| 1 | 1415 |
| 1 | 4027 |
| 1 | 4028 |
| 2 | 202 |
| 2 | 1415 |
| 2 | 4027 |
| 2 | 4028 |
| 3 | 3557 |
| 3 | 9615 |
| 3 | 13017 |
| 3 | 42500 |

Let me say in advance, I know I wasn't filtering inactive items in the query and the results include superfluous columns.

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cross-join `Product` and `Customer`, then anti-join `AuthorizedListItem` which you can do using a `NOT EXISTS`. Do not use `NOT IN` as it doesn't deal with nulls properly.

While in theory you could use a bunch of `AND/OR` conditions to make the join, it's probably better to do four separate subqueries.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW UnauthorizedProductsPerCustomer
AS
SELECT
  c.CustomerID,
  p.ProductID
FROM dbo.Customer c
CROSS JOIN dbo.Product p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM AuthorizedListItem ali
    WHERE ali.ListKey = c.AuthorizedListID
      AND ali.ItemRefNo = p.CategoryKey
      AND ali.Type = 'CATG')
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM AuthorizedListItem ali
    WHERE ali.ListKey = c.AuthorizedListID
      AND ali.ItemRefNo = p.PriceKey
      AND ali.Type = 'PRIC')
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM AuthorizedListItem ali
    WHERE ali.ListKey = c.AuthorizedListID
      AND ali.ItemRefNo = p.VendorKey
      AND ali.Type = 'VNDR')
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM AuthorizedListItem ali
    WHERE ali.ListKey = c.AuthorizedListID
      AND ali.ItemRefNo = p.BrandKey
      AND ali.Type = 'BRND')
  AND p.Inactive = 0;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ef6880/1)

Comment: thank you so much, that's what I was looking for. But a half-*ssed answer was the best I could come up with on my own, and I lack the vocabulary to properly describe the problem.

Answer (score 1):

And the answer is:

If I create a view "AuthorizedProductsPerCustomer" using the query above, this query gives the result I was looking for:

```
SELECT C.CustomerId,
  P.ProductId 
FROM customer C 
CROSS JOIN products P 
WHERE P.ProductId NOT IN 
  (SELECT ProductId 
    FROM AuthorizedProductsPerCustomer A
    WHERE A.CustomerId = C.CustomerId)
```

Comment: Nore, after 24hrs  you can tick it to indicate it is the answer.